# what is bitmap locking?

Tags: graphics, bitmap, locking, render

What is bitmap locking ? why we lock a bitmap ? what is the difference between a locked and unlocked bitmap ? android sdk documentation tells this "the bitmap need to be locked so it will not move while operating" , and stack overflow  tags tell this : "Locking allows different types of resources to be used exclusively by one process at a time " ,well .. that gives an idea but not a answer :/

Comment: OpenGL has no such concept. What API are you talking about. Also, stop using multiple !!! marks. You only need one.

Comment: ok thanks for advice , but  i am a new  member in this web site  ofc that is not a excuse , i need two marks "bitmap" and "locking"

Answer (score 0):

locking is more general than bitmaps and graphics , it is related to memory management and  this paper gives an answer http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locked-Memory-Details.html#Locked-Memory-Details